# Specific tree-style grouping in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to have a different number of subgroups in WPF DataGrid top-level groups?

I need to have something like tree view inside datagrid where expander-like tree nodes contains only some header and bottom-level leaves contains actual data rows. I've tried to accomplish this by a following approach:

```
public class User
{
    public Token Token { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Token
{
    public string PrincipalName { get; set; }

    public Token Child { get; set; }

    public int Depth
    {
        get
        {
            return Child == null ? 1 : Child.Depth + 1;
        }
    }

    public Token Add(string childPrincipalName)
    {
        var token = this;
        while (token.Child != null)
        {
            token = token.Child;
        }

        var child = new Token { PrincipalName = childPrincipalName };
        token.Child = child;
        return this;
    }

    public static Token Create(string principalName)
    {
        return new Token { PrincipalName = principalName };
    }
}
```

Then I create some entries like

```
var users = new List<User>{
                new User{ Name="Hiro Nakamura", Gender="M", Age=24, Country="Japan",
                Token = Token.Create("first")},
                new User{ Name="Mohinder Suresh",Gender="M", Age=26, Country="India",
                Token = Token.Create("second").Add("1")},
                new User { Name = "Claire Bennette", Gender = "F", Age = 19, Country = "USA",
                Token = Token.Create("second").Add("1")},
                new User{ Name="Mohinder Suresh",Gender="M", Age=26, Country="India",
                Token = Token.Create("second").Add("2")},
                new User { Name = "Claire Bennette", Gender = "F", Age = 19, Country = "USA",
                Token = Token.Create("second").Add("2")}
 };
```

and form a collection view:

```
var collection = new ListCollectionView(users);

            int tokenLength = users.Max(u => u.Token.Depth);
            if (tokenLength > 0)
            {
                string token = "Token";
                string child = ".Child";
                string principalName = ".PrincipalName";
                for (int i = 0; i < tokenLength; i++)
                {
                    collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(token + principalName));
                    token += child;
                }
            }
```

The problem is the "second" group has two subgroup: "1" and "2" (which is correct) while the "first" has a subgroup with empty name (which is not what I need). I want the "first" group did not have a subgroup, only "Hiro Nakamura" user in itself.